# updating text inside TextEditor via code - Xcode swift

Tags: swift, xcode, text-editor, multiline, swiftui-texteditor

I'm trying to update the text inside TextEditor via code with no luck and i can't find any examples  - Xcode swift

basically I would like to create a scrollable multiline log that can be

1. highlighted and copy
2. have clickable hyper links

```
 TextEditor(text: $textE)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
```

```
textE = textE + "\n" + textToUpdate2
```

Comment: i found the answer!!! textE.append(contentsOf: "\n" + textToUpdate2)

Comment: still I'm looking for help with adding clickable hyperlinks

Comment: To my knowledge TextEditor does not currently support attributed strings, for this one would need to create a UITextView using UIViewRepresentable.